# Integral over elliptical region, what is going wrong with change of variables?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to find
$$\iint_R \sqrt{x^2+25y^2} dA$$
where $R = \{(x, y)|x^2 + 25y^2 \le 1 \}$ using change of variables. I made the substitution
$$x = 5 r \cos(\theta)$$
$$y = r \sin (\theta)$$
The Jacobian determinant is $5r$ and the new region should be $S = \{(r, \theta)|0 \le r \le 1 \text{ and } 0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi \}.$ Thus, our integral should be equal to
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 r \cdot(5r) dr d\theta = \dfrac{10 \pi}{3}.$$

However, the correct answer is $2 \pi/15$. Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: For comparison purposes, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2915722/86846 (not a duplicate of this).

Comment: @abiessu Thanks, I will take a look

Comment: You may (but you needn't) use `\iint` for the first integral instead of doubled `\int`.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks for the tip, that looks much better.

Comment: There is also `\iiint`, should you ever need to integrate over volume. :)

Comment: @CiaPan Yeah I assumed there must be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is in the range of $r$. After substituting $x = 5r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$ into $x^2 + 25 y^2 \leq 1$, we can get
$$ 25 r^2 \cos(\theta) + 25 r^2 \sin(\theta) = 25 r^2 \leq 1 $$.
Since $r\geq0$, in total we get $0 \leq r \leq \frac{1}{5}$.

Another one is that $\sqrt{x^2 + 25 y^2}$ should be $5r$, but you put $r$ instead.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much!